The form of an odd polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3-t]$
Let $\iota: t \mapsto -t$ be the involution on $\mathbb{C}[t]$;
it is clear that w.r.t. $\iota$, the symmetric elements are even polynomials
(all monomials are of even degrees)
and the skew-symmetric elements are odd polynomials
(all monomials are of odd degrees).
Denote the set of symmetric elements in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ (= even polynomials) by $S$ and the set
of skew-symmetric elements in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ (= odd polynomials) by $K$.

Let $A=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$.
Since $t^2 \in A$, we have $S \subseteq A$, and actually, $S \subsetneq A$,
since $A$ also contains odd polynomials.
$t \notin A$, and it is easy to see that
$A \cap K = \{ a_{2n+1}t^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}t^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_5t^5+a_3t^3 \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{C} \}$, namely, odd polynomials without $a_1t$.

Let $B=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3-t]$.
$A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic, by the answer to
this question.
Since $t^2 \in B$, we have $S \subseteq B$, and actually, $S \subsetneq B$,
since $B$ also contains odd polynomials.
$t \notin B$, and now it is not easy (at least to me) to see which odd polynomials exactly belong to
$B \cap K$.

Question: Is it possible to find the general form of an element of $B \cap K$?

A partial answer:
An element of $B \cap K$ of degree $3$ is of the form $c(t^3-t)$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$.
An element of $B \cap K$ of degree $5$ is of the form $at^5+bt^3+ct$,
where $b=-a-c$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.
Indeed, elements of $B \cap K$ involving degrees $\leq 5$ include:
$t^3-t,t^2(t^3-t)=t^5-t^3$, hence a general element of degree $\leq 5$ is
$u(t^5-t^3)+v(t^3-t)=ut^5+(-u+v)t^3-vt$, for some $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$.
If we denote: $a=u,b=-u+v,c=-v$, we obtain
$at^5+bt^3+ct$,
with $b=-a-c$.
Any help is welcome; thank you!

@HankScorpio, thank you very much! Could you please write your comment as an answer? I will delete several computations in my question..

Did you mean that $p$ is even? Since your form is a product of two odd polynomials, which is an even polynomial.

For example, $\deg(f) \leq 5$, $f=at^5+bt^3+ct$ with $b=-a-c$, is of your form: $(at^2+a+b)(t^3-t)$, with even $p=at^2+a+b$; indeed, $(at^2+a+b)(t^3-t)=at^5-at^3+(a+b)t^3-(a+b)t=at^5+bt^3-(a+b)t$, and $-(a+b)=c$.

No, I mean that $p$ is a one-variable polynomial which is odd, and then you plug $t^3-t$ in to it. The other interpretation is obvious nonsense, as you wrote 3 comments about. I don't think this question will have any lasting value for anyone other than you, so I will decline to write an answer.

@HankScorpio, thank you for your clarification. Thanks.

Uhoh, that's not even right - $t^2\cdot(t^3-t)$ isn't of the form I spoke of above. Nevermind, shouldn't have commented in the first place.

Thank you very much for all your comments!

In a computation I deleted, using the relation of $t^2$ and $t^3-t$, I arrived at $W(t^3-t)$ for a general odd monomial of $B$, where $W$ is even of a special form, so the product form $p(t^3-t)$, with $p \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ even (sum of even $W_i$'s), seems ok; I just have not computed exactly the sum of such monomials $W_i(t^3-t)$ since the sum of the $W_i$'s seems complicated, but at least we can say that $B \cap K \subseteq {p(t^3-t)}_{p \ \text{is even}}$.

I would start finding generators and relations for the algebra $B$. And then finding a vector space basis. From there, things should be easy.

@MartinBrandenburg, thank you for your comment. In a previous version I have considered the generators $U=t^2$ and $V=t^3-t$ with relation $V^2-U^3+2U^2-U=0$, then an odd monomial is of the form $W(t^3-t)$, where $W$ is even of specific form and we should consider sums of such monomials. I will think about the vector space approach.

Specifically, I think that $B \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2 - x(x-1)^2)$, so the monomials $x^n$ and $x^m y$ form a vector space basis. The involution here is $x \mapsto x$, $y \mapsto -y$. So it's very easy now.

Thank you again. So your $x$ and $y$ is my $U$ and $V$. If I am interested in odd polynomials of $B$, then they are sums of $U^nV^{2m+1}$, since otherwise we get even monomials. If you would like to answer my question, please, it would be nice. The exact form is still interesting for me, not just the inclusion $B \cap K \subseteq {p(t^3-t)}_{p \ \text{is even}}$, which I think/hope is correct.

Perhaps you meant that an odd element is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_iU^iV=(\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i U^i)V$.

In the deleted previous version there is a misprint and $2$ should be replaced by $n$, namely, $W=t^{2n+6m}-2mt^{2n+6m-2}+\cdots$.

@MartinBrandenburg, please, could you explain (in an answer or a comment) if there is a more specific form than the form I have found?

Let $x := t^2$ and $y := t^3 - t = t(t^2-1)$. Then $y^2 = x(x-1)^2$, so we get a homomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras from $C := \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/\langle Y^2 - X(X-1)^2 \rangle$ to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ mapping $X \mapsto x$, $Y \mapsto y$. You can verify that it is injective, by using the vector space basis $\{X^n : n \geq 0\} \cup \{X^n Y : n \geq 0\}$ of $C$ over $\mathbb{C}$. The image is clearly $B$. Hence, $C \cong B$.
Under the isomorphism $C \to B$, the involution* $t \mapsto -t$ of $B$ corresponds to the involution $X \mapsto X$, $Y \mapsto -Y$ of $C$. From the basis it is clear that the subspace of "skew-fixed points" of this involution (those elements $c$ that get mapped to $-c$ by the involution) is generated by $\{X^n Y : n \geq 0\}$. The image of this under the isomorphism $C \to B$ is generated by $\{x^n y : n \geq 0\} = \{t^{2n} (t^3-t) : n \geq 0\}$ as a vector space. This is the subspace of polynomials of the form $p(t^2) \cdot (t^3-t)$ for $p \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.
*Be careful, in operator theory at least, the word "involution" refers to a map that is conjugate-linear, but here we only talk about linear maps.

Thank you very much!
